How can i add validation between steps of a v-stepper?
Code
I have a Vue component using v-stepper that looks like this:
<template>
  <v-stepper
    v-model="step"
    :items="items"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.1>
      <v-form>
        //content of step 1
      </v-form>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.2>
      <v-form>
        //content of step 2
      </v-form>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.3>
      <v-form>
        //content of step 3
      </v-form>
    </template>

  </v-stepper>
</template>

It's a v-stepper with a <template v-slot:item.n> with a <v-form> inside of it for each step, but i don't mind changing this structure to solve the problem.
What i want
I simply want to be able to validate each step before going to the next one, i want the user to only be able to click "Next" once all the fields on each step have been filled.
I either want to know how to i trigger the "go to the next step" function, because if i knew that, i could create a custom button and a function that is triggered every time this button is pressed, but i don't know what that function might be.
Or, i wanted to know if there's a way to access the built-in v-stepper-actions (the ones that already work and already come pre-built in the v-slots) and change their behavior.
What i've tried
This seemingly simple problem has made me binge-read the docs, try multiple ChatGPT prompts, look for reddit posts, other SO questions and even GitHub discussions. I'm sure there must be someone who's asked this before, but i couldn't find any solutions that worked for me. Some of the things i've tried were:
Creating my own <v-btn> or <v-stepper-actions>. I tried this, which i found in another SO post:
<v-stepper-actions
  :disabled="disabled"
  @click:next="Validate(next)"
  @click:prev="prev"
></v-stepper-actions>

but the buttons simply don't seem to work or even be clickable at all (they appear clickable, but do nothing)
I tried a possible built-in prop from a 2018's piece of documentation, changing my v-stepper to this:
  <v-stepper
    v-model="step"
    :items="items"
    @before-next-step="Validate()"
  >

But this also seemingly does nothing.
I've tried a multitude of different v-stepper templates and methods, more than i could remember and list here, with no success.
Does anyone have any idea on how to do that? I'm sure there must be a very simple fix, but i simply can't find it anywhere.

The simplest way is to use VStepper's @update:modelValue event and undo the change if validation fails:
<v-stepper
  v-model="step" 
  @update:model-value="() => validate() || step--"
  ...


The reset is handled before the view updates, so it is not visible to the user.
see playground example

Using the VStepper's next slot gives you more control:
<v-stepper>
  <template #next="{props: { onClick }}">
    <v-btn variant="tonal" text="next" @click="validate() && onClick()" />
  </template>
  ...

see playground example
With this, instead of going back, you can abort going forward if validation fails, which is necessary if validation runs async. Or you can disable the button if data is missing, which gives visible feedback to the user.
Note that the props.onClick slot prop is currently not documented, which leads to error messages. Manually updating VStepper's modelValue (i.e. @click="validate() && step++") might be preferable for now.
